# High CPU usage from ffmpeg decoding rtsp to v4l2loopback

Tags: ffmpeg, armbian, v4l2loopback

I got a orangepi5 that has hardware decoders for h264,hevc and other formats. I am using armibian Armbian 23.5.5 Jammy CLI kernel legacy 5.10.160. I've installed a custom [ffmpeg that uses RockChip MPP](https://github.com/hbiyik/FFmpeg) and hence enables those decoders.

I am trying to use those hardware decoders to create a loopback device at `/dev/video0`. For example, using the following command:

```
ffmpeg -rtsp_transport tcp -y -c:v  h264_rkmpp_decoder -re -i rtsp://admin:passwd@ipcam-front-up:554/stream=0 -c:v rawvideo -pix_fmt yuv420p -f v4l2  /dev/video0
```

*It works* ***but*** if I look at `htop` I see 12 processes/threads  besides the main thread/process that spawned them (by their process group number) and I get ***~7% of average CPU usage***.

If I am not transcoding anything, why that? If I for example use only the bellow I get only ***1% of average CPU usage .***

```
ffmpeg -rtsp_transport tcp -y -c:v  h264_rkmpp_decoder -i rtsp://admin:passwd@ipcam-front-up:554/stream=0 -f null -
```

Why `-f v4l2` is creating that much overhead. Or what am I doing wrong? I just want to make that stream available for another software ([motion project](https://github.com/Motion-Project/motion)) that cannot use that hardware decoder directly.